# auto vacuum/vacuum not releasing dead rows in PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, vacuum, autovacuum

All,

Please suggest here, auto vacuum/vacuum is not releasing the dead rows for a table in postgreSQL 9.6 version, can anyone help what needs to be checked here or is there any parameter tune to remove dead rows.

Regards,
Varun

Comment: please post output of vacuum and pg_stat_* to see what you mean

Comment: Dear Vao,could you please elaborate what exactly you want.